# iOS Sharing .h file between main app and share extension

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I have all constant key in .h file. After that, I share that one between my main app and my share extension. However, my share extension doesn't seem to read that file and I can't use constant key from there. How shall I do?

Comment: Did you #import the .h file in the share extension code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an embedded framework that is imported by both the app target and the share extension target. That is how to share code of any kind between targets.

Comment: There's no requirement to making an embedded framework, although if the code is large it will save memory.